# Angular 2 ngModelChange not working on second dropdown

Tags: jquery, angular

I have two dropdown menus with two different ngModelChange methods:

```
<div class="mb-40">
  <div class="tit03 mb-20">Type of Healthpros</div>
  <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="pros" (ngModelChange)="onSelectProfessions($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let item of professions" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.text}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="mb-40">
  <div class="tit03 mb-20">Type of Specialization</div>
  <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="spec" (ngModelChange)="onSelectSpecialities($event)">
    <option *ngFor="let item of specialities" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.text}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Call these methods:

```
onSelectSpecialities($value){
   console.log("Here");
}

onSelectProfessions($value){
   console.log("Here 2");
}
```

The problem is that onSelectProfessions gets called when I change its dropdown menu, but onSelectSpecialities never gets called :( It only gets called when I complete remove the onSelectProfessions in the HTML, what am I doing wrong?

Here is my full Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
import * as globals from '../../../app/globals';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { UserService } from '../../../services/user.service';
import { UtilService } from '../../../services/util.service';
import { DataService } from '../../../services/data.service';

/*INSTALL*/
import swal from 'sweetalert2';

declare var $: JQuery;

declare global {
  interface JQuery {
    (selector: string): JQuery;
    rating(): JQuery;
  }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-list-professional',
    templateUrl: './list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./list.component.css']
})
export class ListProfessionalComponent {

    review = {rating:4}
    professionals = [];
    professions = {};
    specialities = {};



    constructor(private userService: UserService, private utilService: UtilService, private dataService: DataService){

        this.textSearch  = "";

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {

        this.utilService.blockUiStart();

        this.userService.getAllProfessionals().subscribe(data => {

            this.professionals = data;

            this.dataService.getProfessions().subscribe(data => { 
                this.professions = data;
            });

            this.dataService.getSpecialities().subscribe(data => {
                this.specialities = data;
            });

            this.utilService.blockUiStop();

        });

    }

    onSubmit($value){
        console.log(this.textSearch);
        this.utilService.blockUiStart();
        this.userService.getProfessionalsByUsername(this.textSearch).subscribe(data => {
            this.professionals = data;
            this.utilService.blockUiStop();
        });
    }


    public onSelectSpecialities($value){

        console.log("Here");

        this.utilService.blockUiStart();
        this.userService.getProfessionalsBySpecialities($value).subscribe(data => {
            this.professionals = data;
            this.utilService.blockUiStop();
        });

    }

    public onSelectProfessions($value){

        this.utilService.blockUiStart();
        this.userService.getProfessionalsByProfessions($value).subscribe(data => {
            this.professionals = data;
            this.utilService.blockUiStop();
        });

    }

}
```

and here is my full data:

```
[{"id":1,"text":"Cardiology"},{"id":2,"text":"Clinical neurophysiology"},{"id":3,"text":"Endocrinology"},{"id":4,"text":"Geriatrics"},{"id":5,"text":"Internal medicine"},{"id":6,"text":"Nuclear medicine"},{"id":7,"text":"Ophthalmology"}]
```

and

```
[{"id":1,"text":"Health Technologist"},{"id":2,"text":"Sport Medicine Physician"},{"id":3,"text":"Medical Receptionist"},{"id":4,"text":"Psychiatry"}]
```

Comment: Is this markup inside a `form` tag?

Comment: No they are not.

Comment: Do the `specialities` have distinct `id` values? Try displaying them in the control with `{{item.id}} - {{item.text}}`.

Comment: I updated my code with the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not defined 'pros' and 'spec' related binding in component classs. kindly define these model binding variables in component class. 100 % Your problem get solved.
Have executed your code, faced same problem. then got solution and this conclusion.

Comment: I changed the class name of the second div to b-42 and that did not work

Comment: You have not defined 'pros' and 'spec'. kindly define these model binding variables in component class. 100 % Your problem get solved.

Comment: I am fairly new to angular js, what would this look like?

Comment: Code in  your html ----------->  [(ngModel)]="pros" . This 'pros' binding must be defined in your component class. Similarly for code -------------> [(ngModel)]="spec". This 'spec' binding must be defined in component class.   Just add this in component class.                                 
pros:String;
spec:String;

Comment: Hey! That worked! Thank you.....any idea why I am getting this error? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51620618/angular-2-cannot-find-a-differ-supporting-object-object-object-of-type-obje

Answer (score 0):

Just copied your html and added my setup code and everything seems to be working fine.

Try the following code:

Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
selector: 'app-multi-dropdown',
templateUrl: 'multi-dropdown.component.html'
})
export class MultiDropDownComponent {

professions: any[] = [
    { id: '1', text: 'Professional1' },
    { id: '2', text: 'Professional2' },
    { id: '3', text: 'Professional3' },
    { id: '4', text: 'Professional4' }
];

specialities: any[] = [
    { id: '1', text: 'specialities1' },
    { id: '2', text: 'specialities2' },
    { id: '3', text: 'specialities3' },
    { id: '4', text: 'specialities4' }
];

public onSelectSpecialities($value) {
    console.log('Specialities changed');

}

public onSelectProfessions($value) {
    console.log('Professional changed');
}
}
```

HTML:

```
    <h1>Multidrop down compnent</h1>
    <div class="mb-40">
        <div class="tit03 mb-20">Type of Healthpros</div>
        <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="pros" (ngModelChange)="onSelectProfessions($event)">
            <option *ngFor="let item of professions" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.text}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-40">
        <div class="tit03 mb-20">Type of Specialization</div>
        <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="spec" (ngModelChange)="onSelectSpecialities($event)">
            <option *ngFor="let item of specialities" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.text}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: That looks exactly what I have, do get this error: `Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

Comment: The error concludes the the data for *ngFor is not of array type.Can you share your component code